# c++ mysql connection failure

Tags: c++, mysql, database-connection

I try to connect to my MySql database with c++ but it won't connect and I cant figure out why. The Instance of the MYSQL object was initialised and I also tried to connect to my database with Java and Php and it worked...

The Mysql server is not hosted by me, it's hosted by an German server provider so I suggest on the server side will be everything ok.

Also the libs and includes are linked correct since the initialisation of my MYSQL instance works fine.
The mysql version I use is 5.0.X

this is the line of code where I try to connect to the database:

```
MYSQL *connect = mysql_init(NULL);
mysql_real_connect(connect, "xxxxx.db.1and1.com", "dboXXXXXX", "XXXXXX", "dbXXXXXX", 0, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: Did they open the port to public? I doubt.

Comment: I guess, because I can connect to the database from my Java and PHP applications with the standard port

Comment: Java application? double confirm the connectivity by `telnet xxxxx.db.1and1.com 3306` in Terminal / Command Prompt / Shell, from the same machine of C++ application.

Comment: I tested the connection from my Java application to make that I get this error only in my c++ app, but it seems that something's wrong with my machine or network because I cannot connect to the database with telnet and port 3306

Comment: You probably need to figure out whether default port 3306 is used or not.

Comment: The FAQ of my provider says that they're using default port 3306 and also my application does

Comment: the Java application is located in the same machine as your C++ application? Make sure your firewall / router does not block the network traffic